# Floating Action Menu , Shadow cut by Square from Right and Bottom in Lollipop and above versions

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have problem similar to this [link](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/issues/195)but reproducing only in lollipop and above versions.

Also am using the same [tutorial](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) for my implementation.

Somehow using the below code, i am able to remove the square shadow using below code:

```
Button fab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
//Outline outline = new Outline();
//outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);
//fab.setOutline(outline);  
ViewOutlineProvider viewOutlineProvider = new ViewOutlineProvider() {
        @Override
        public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
            // Or read size directly from the view's width/height
            int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_size);
            outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);
        }
    };
fab.setOutlineProvider(viewOutlineProvider);
```

But using above code, I am again getting a weird (**half circle**) shadow on the top of floating action button, like this:

[image]

Also the code is removing the shadow n I dont want to remove that.

Comment: I had already tried adding the margin as <item name="android:layout_marginRight">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">24dp</item> but didn't work

Comment: margin might not work in some specific containers and alignments (e.g. RelativeLayout. Also Coordinator is buggy in this sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you and solved by adding this:

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```